# Are all products of trigonometric functions integrable?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I have a feeling that this question has a really obvious answer, so forgive me if it turns out to be trivial.

That being said, my question is whether all functions involving trigonometric functions and their products/quotients *only* have a closed-form integral. (I know that functions such as $\int \cos(x^2) \, dx$ have no closed form, so I'll restrict the exponent on the variable to $1$.) I'm aware that we can integrate functions of the form
$$\int \sin^n(ax)\cos^m(bx) \, dx$$
I'm also pretty confident that the same can be said for products involving tangents and secants as as well as cotangents and cosecants. But for an arbitrary product with $n$ factors and a random combination of trigonometric functions, it's not at all clear to me. Of course, we can always convert the other trigonometric functions to sines and cosines, so we end up with determining whether any product or quotient of sines and cosines to certain powers can be integrated. Or, can
$$\int \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\sin^{a_i}(b_ix)\cos^{c_i}(d_ix)}{\sum_{j=1}^m\sin^{e_j} (f_jx) \cos^{g_j}(h_jx)} \, dx$$
be integrated, where $b_i, d_i, f_j, h_j \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a_i, c_i, e_j, g_j \in \mathbb{N}$?

This, however, is a monstrosity, so let's assume that each $f_j$ and $h_j$ is equal to some $b_i$ and $d_i$, respectively, so we can remove the denominator:
$$\int \sum_{i=1}^n\sin^{a_i} (b_ix) \cos^{c_i} (d_ix) \, dx$$
(Now, $a_i, c_i \in \mathbb{Z}$).
I'm also interested in the case where all the arguments are just $x$, that is $b_i, d_i  = 1$, if that helps:
$$\int \sum_{i=1}^n\sin^{a_i}(x)\cos^{c_i}(x) \, dx$$

Comment: The 3rd & 4th displays are each finite sums of terms of the type in the 1st line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some general theorems in this area, which are generalization of some results by Liouville. The answer to your question is that ratios of the kind you've written admit elementary antiderivatives, in that the antiderivative is also of the above form. [Check the following reference.](http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/cmi/library/academy/LectureNotes05/Conrad.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

For integer values of *k* and *n*, $\sin kx$ and $\cos nx$ can always be expressed as a [linear combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Multiple-angle_formulae) of products of powers of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. Then, using the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution), we are left with solving the integral of a [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). See also [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).